# Better to choose 8 x 2.5'' or 4 x 3.5'' HDD for a SAN server?

Tags: raid, storage, storage-area-network

I would like to build a new server primarily used as a Backup/SAN device. The specifications are 16T storage capability, access through a 100 Base-T network.

Is it better to use a RAID over 8 x 3T 2.5'' HDD or a RAID over 4 x 6T 3.5'' HDD?

Does it make really a difference?

Considering the hardware, I am thinking about a HPE ProLiant DL120 or a DL360.

Comment: Is that 100 Base-T a typo? Because filling (and recovering) a good fraction of that 16 TB will take quite a long time. Even a modest 500GB will take half a day to transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup and SAN are too very different use-cases, typically a backup server will require larger disks with better sequential throughput whereas a SAN or NAS can have a much wider range to requirements - from the same big/slow disks to the fastest NVMe storage and anything in between. That said you've mentioned both the 6TB 3.5's and the 3TB 2.5's - the 2.5's will be a little quicker just due to the smaller distance the heads have to move.

I do hope you don't plan using RAID 5, there's all manner of documentation and justification I can send you but essentially it's dangerous when used with disks of this size and is effectively dead in 2016 (and has been for a while in fact) - stick to R1/10 or R6/60. If you were to use R6 for this then with the 3.5's you end up with ~12TB of usable space (2 x 6TB data and 2 x 6TB parity) whereas if you use the 2.5's you end up with ~18TB usable space (6 x 3TB data and 2 x 3TB parity).

Hope this helps, and btw either of those servers are great, personally I love the DL3x0's but the 1x0's are good too, depends on your budget.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why RAID5 is not a good solution and why it is effectively dead in 2016? With RAID6 I need 8 disks, so only the 2.5'' solution will work, right?

Comment: Just google it, basically with >1TB disks the Unrecoverable Error Rates of the disks is such that any rebuild will be *certain* to introduce an area of unrecoverable data - basically you lose some of your data every time you have to do a disk rebuild - plus with R5 if you have a second disk failure during rebuild (not a remote scenario, it's the busiest disks usually get for any length of time) you lose everything. We've had SO many new users come to us in a panic because they've lost data or whole volumes since SF started that we go out of our way to warn people away from it.